# fscanf fixed string size using macro

Tags: string, gcc, macros, scanf

I want to parse an ip from file using fscanf (C code using gcc).
so, I want to do:

```
char myip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
fscanf(file, "%16s", myip);
```

but, I don't want to hardcode the number 16, so I'm trying to use macro, but it doesn't work.

```
#define _STRIFY(x) #x
char myip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
fscanf(file, "%" _STRIFY(INET_ADDRSTRLEN) "s", myip);
```

here is the error I get

```
unknown conversion character type 'N' format
```

so what is wrong with my code ?

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Don't forget that if your buffer is of length INET_ADDRSTRLEN, the number to be specified to `sprintf()` is INET_ADDRSTRLEN-1.  This makes macro-based solutions hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
char format[14];
sprintf(format, "%%%ds", INET_ADDRSTRLEN-1);
fscanf(file, format, myip);
```

Comment: +1: with an appropriate definition for `s`, which might be better named `format`, perhaps.  This works best if INET_ADDRSTRLEN evaluates to an expression.

Comment: As noted in a comment to the main question, the length needs to be `INET_ADDRSTRLEN - 1` to avoid overflow of a buffer of length `INET_ADDRSTRLEN`; the null is not included in the length in `scanf()` et al.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
#define stringify_1(x...)  #x
#define stringify(x...)    stringify_1(x)

char myip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
fscanf(file, "%" stringify(INET_ADDRSTRLEN) "s", myip);
```

These are the stringify function-like macros used in the Linux kernel.

See in my comments you are vulnerable to a buffer overflow if you use the same value for the buffer size and the size in the conversion specification. Use for example `INET_ADDRSTRLEN + 1` in the buffer declaration to avoid the possibility of the overflow.

Comment: +1: This works when INET_ADDSTRLEN evaluates to a simple number; not so hot if it evaluates to an expression.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler by the way there is an off-by-one buffer overflow in his program, if the buffer is `INET_ADDSTRLEN` bytes, he'd need `INET_ADDSTRLEN - 1` for the `%<size>s` conversion specification as the null character is not counted. As he cannot use an expression for the `stringify` macro, a solution is to declare `myip` with size `INET_ADDRSTRLEN + 1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually I'm just seeing you wrote a similar comment in the OP question

Comment: You'll need to remove or seriously modify your `*` solution; in `scanf()`, that's assignment suppression, not 'take length of argument' like it would be in `printf()`.  Even in `printf()`, you'd need a cast to `int` on the result of `sizeof` since `size_t` is not guaranteed to the same size as `int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well spotted, I thought the behavior was the same as with `fprintf`.